# How to enable mod_unique_id in IBM Http server?

Tags: apache, websphere, ibmhttpserver

How to enable **mod_unique_id** in IBM Http Server? I am using **WAS** for deployment. I didnt find any documentation online. Kindly share any link or steps if you have done already.

Following link confirms that it is supported by IBM Http server:
[link](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.ihs.doc/ihs/rihs_apachemods.html)

Answer (score 1):

This module requires no configuration other than being loaded. It is loaded in the default configuration file.  Just check for this line:

```
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
```

And add it if it's not present.  That's all there is to it.